# Is Adding custom android skins to virtual device missing in ADT Eclipse(Juno)

Tags: android, device

I'm using the Eclipse IDE (Juno 4.2) and the latest Android/Google ADK.
The ability to load/use custom skins seems to have disappeared. When creating a device in the AVD (android virtual device manager), it was possible to specify a skin from drop-down {skins had to be loaded into the sdk/android-##/skins}. The directory(s) are still there but adding skins does not allow/permit selecting it in any part of the virtual device creation process.

I'm running Eclipse Juno 4.2 on both a windows and mac os.

developer.android.com docs still show UI that for selecting custom skins.
Is is possible to still use custom skins is there now a restriction on skins?

Answer (score 5):

The only way I've found to do this is to manually edit the config.ini file for your AVD.  Change the field "skin_name" to the name of the skin you want to use and change "skin_path" to the path to the skin, relative to the sdk directory.

So if your skin was part of an SDK add-on, an AVD config.ini that looks like this:

```
skin_name=1280x800
skin_path=1280x800
```

Would be changed to:

```
skin_name=MyDevice
skin_path=add-ons\addon_device_vendor_api\skins\MyDevice
```

Or in your example:

```
skin_path=platforms\android-##\skins\MySkin
```

The Docs don't appear to have been updated for revision 21 of the ADT yet, so maybe they'll have more information in the future.  I'd really like to know if there's a way to do this from within the Device Manager, but this is the only way I've found to do it.

Comment: where can I find this config.ini file for AVD?

Answer (score 0):

After Update your ADT to version 21.

**In Older Version each time you have to set `Add Custom` Screen if you want custom Device Configurations.**

In ADT21 Oversion you can get this thing done by

> **open `AVD Manager`, u can define your custom screen in `"Device Definition"`**

**Alternative (Much Easier approach)**

> in Newest Version you Don't Need to Set Custom Device
>   Configurations from the above Suggestion as much easier way is available for it. you >Just Have to Make Emulator With your Device 
>   Configurations and after you will see those Configurations with
>   Emulator Name Inside `Graphical Layout` of XML

like after Created my Emulator of Nexus7 Emulator with Android 4.2 with Name as "Nexus7_Android_4.2" i will get this Device Configuration in Graphical Layout of xml automatically.

Below is the Screen Shot of it.

[image]

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: this is when you create emulator, what if I want to use custom skin?